# How to spy on $window.confirm with Karma / Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using Angular and my controller has:

```
        clearCustom: function () {
            // make sure they are doing this on purpose
            if (!$window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone number?')) return;

            if ($scope.model.originalPhoneSms === $scope.model.phoneCustom) {
                $scope.model.patient.phoneSms = '';
                $scope.model.patient.phoneSmsVerified = false;
                $scope.model.originalPhoneSms = '';
                cache.set('patient', 'currentPatient', $scope.model.patient);
            }
            $scope.model.phoneCustom = '';
            $scope.save();
        }
```

My test is:

```
it('should confirm that the user is trying to clear the custom phone number', function() {
    scope.clearCustom();

    var windowMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$window', ['confirm']);

    expect(windowMock.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But it fails with `Expected spy $window.confirm to have been called.`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried actually setting up the spy _before_ calling your function under test (clearCustom)?

Comment: spy object is a mocked object, you are not injecting it into scope in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the spy before invoking the method on the system under test. I cant see your setup function, but you might need to pass the controller your spied on `$window` object.

```
var $window;

beforeEach(inject([$controller, function ($controller) {
    $window = jasmine.createSpyObj('$window', ['confirm']);

    $controller('your.module.controller.foo', {
        $window: $window
    });
}]));

it('should confirm that the user is trying to clear the custom phone number', function() {
    scope.clearCustom();

    expect($window.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Same result: `Expected spy $window.confirm to have been called.`

Comment: Edited, I cant see your controller instantiation in beforeEach, but you need to pass the mock window object as a dependency if you dont already. you can also spy on angulars default $window object by injecting it into the beforeEach.

Comment: This worked for me: `spyOn($window, 'confirm').and.returnValue(false);`